# MacVim Visual Selection Delete moves back 3 extra chars

Tags: vim, selection, backspace

Using MacVim with https://github.com/carlhuda/janus installed, when I select a visual or insert block and hit backspace, the cursor jumps back an extra 3 spaces. Anyone else see this? Makes it real annoying to do my favorite shift-cmd-up to select and delete empty lines.

```
set backspace=indent,eol,start
```

is the only reference to backspace I see in vimrc and gvimrc.

Selection made:

[image: Made selection with mouse or shift-arrow]

After hitting backspace:

[image: Where the cursor ends up after backspace key]

Anyone know of a quick way to fix this? I'm working through http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Backspace_and_delete_problems to see if any of the remedies there can help but I don't see anything at first glance.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is a little old, but the two previous answers led me in the right direction. Looks like snipMate was the culprit.

Edit this file:

```
 ~/.vim/after/plugin/snipMate.vim
```

And comment out this line:

```
snor <bs> b<bs>
```

This solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you're lucky and it's a mapping,  `:verbose vmap <BS>` would tell you where it's being set. Otherwise, you'll have to see if the problem is your vimrc or a plugin, run MacVim from the terminal with `mvim -N -u NORC -U NORC` to rule your vimrc and gvimrc out, then `mvim --noplugin` to rule plugins out.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful flag...it seems to be *some* setting but I have a hunch it's not anything directly related to <BS> mappings, since I deleted an autoindent line and the behavior changed slightly for certain blocks of text. Still not consistent, and all I want is the cursor to stay exactly where it is after delete.

Answer (score 1):

Removing snipMate seemed to do the trick for me.